# Android Cloud back-up

Tags: android

I was going through the cloud back up.
In there it says that to use the Google provided Android Backup Service, i need to register my application which will give me Backup Service Key.
My question is how will the same application on different devices receive their specific data?

Example:- the application remembers choice of burger and orders it from the online store:

It backs up application data like choice of burgers, payment gateway etc.

Person A and Person B is using the same application on different devices and have different choice of burgers and gateways.

So when the data are retrieved during re-install how will Person A have his choices and Person B his?
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are identified by the primary Google Account on the phone:

> When an Android-powered device that uses Android Backup Service runs your application, the system verifies that your Backup Service Key is valid and Android Backup Service saves the user's data to Google servers using the primary Google account on the device.

See http://code.google.com/android/backup/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [Swarm's Cloud Data](http://swarmconnect.com/cloud_data) feature, which provides an online save system (very similar to SharedPreferences), which could easily save small pieces of data like you mentioned.  Data persists across multiple devices (tied to user account).

Answer (score 0):

I am from Skiller and you can do it easily with our Skiller SDK API. Follow this steps:
1. Register as a developer on our site [www.skiller-games.com](http://www.skiller-games.com)
2. Create new application, which will generate your application id, key and secret.
3. Download the Android SDK and link the jar to your project.
4. Init the application with the key and secret and use these simple APIs:

```
SKApplication.getInstance().storePersistentData(data, listener);
//data - The data you want to store across the devices/platforms per user
//listener - will notify you if the data was stored properly

SKApplication.getInstance().getPersistentData(listener);
//listener - will return the data you previously stored for this user
```

If you feel like trying out our SDK we would be glad to provide you more details.
For more info just send an email to developers@skiller-games.com

Enjoy!